# retrieving original data from phase and magnitude of Fourier transform

Tags: fft, dft, phase, magnitude

I use this snippet of python code to transform data to Fourier phase and magnitude and then retrieving original data.

```
from random import randint as RI
import numpy.fft as FFT
import math

w = 4
h = 4
random_range = 255

vals = [[] for i in range(h)]

for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        vals[i].append(RI(0,random_range))

fftc = FFT.fft2(vals) 

magnitudes = [[] for i in range(h)]
phases = [[] for i in range(h)]

for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        magnitudes[i].append(math.sqrt(fftc[i][j].real**2+fftc[i][j].imag**2))
        phases[i].append(math.atan(fftc[i][j].imag/fftc[i][j].real))

for_ifft = [[] for i in range(h)]

for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        rl = magnitudes[i][j]*math.cos(phases[i][j])
        im = magnitudes[i][j]*math.sin(phases[i][j])
        for_ifft[i].append(complex(rl,im))


ifftc = FFT.ifft2(for_ifft)


print vals
print ifftc
```

When i compare outputs, results are different. for example two typical outputs are:

```
//original data
[[115, 4, 33, 91], [228, 123, 46, 111], [83, 227, 81, 55], [229, 188, 138, 41]]

//retrieved data from phase and magnitude informations
[[ 309,182.25,105,57.25],[ 33,118.75,120.50,116.25],[ 148,128.75,79,94.75],[ 165,112.25,-6.50,29.75]]
```

I know the theory behind it. for example for calculating phase and magnitude we do this :

```
Magnitude = Square_Root(real*real+imaginary*imaginary)
Phase = Inverse_Tangent(imaginary/real)
```

and for calculating complex number from magnitude and phase we do this :

```
Real = Magnitude * cos(Phase)
Imaginary = Magnitude * sin(Phase)
```

So, what is the cause of problem. Is it a data scaling issue.

Comment: You should use "atan2" instead of "atan" to calculate the phase, because atan doesn't work in all quadrants.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I will use "atan2(Imaginary,Real)" instead of "atan(Imaginary/Real)".

Comment: @JimClay: You should convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change how you're calculating the phase from "atan" to "atan2".  The reason is that atan doesn't work in all quadrants.  More on atan2 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).